# Cannot load Google Map through AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show Google map in my html . here is my code:

**html:**

```
    <div class="map-content">
      <div map-marker="" ng-model="searchLocation" class="mapmarker"></div>
    </div>
```

**js:**

```
app.directive('mapMarker',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope:{
            searchLocation: '=ngModel'
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.searchLocation = {
                latitude: 48.137273,
                longitude: 11.575251
            };
        },
        resolve: {
            load: function () {

            }
        },
        link: function(scope , element, attrs , ngModel){

            var mapOptions;
            var googleMap;
            var searchMarker;
            var searchLatLng;

            ngModel.$render = function(){

                searchLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.searchLocation.latitude, scope.searchLocation.longitude);

                mapOptions = {
                    center: searchLatLng,
                    zoom: 12,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                googleMap = new google.maps.Map(element[0],mapOptions);

                searchMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: searchLatLng,
                    map: googleMap,
                    draggable: true
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(searchMarker, 'dragend', function(){

                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        scope.searchLocation.latitude = searchMarker.getPosition().lat();
                        scope.searchLocation.longitude = searchMarker.getPosition().lng();
                    });
                }.bind(this));

            };

            scope.$watch('searchMarker', function(value){
                var myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.searchLocation.latitude, scope.searchLocation.longitude);
                searchMarker.setPosition(myPosition);
            }, true);
        }
    }
});
```

Also, I include

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`

It knows script file but it can't show map on my html. Any suggestion?

Comment: What does console say?

Comment: where do you included the api script?

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of modifications your example works: [see my plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/rqKoTB9Opc0h2e1vM8kT?p=preview).

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .directive('mapMarker',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope:{
            searchLocation: '=mapMarker'
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.searchLocation = {
                latitude: 48.137273,
                longitude: 11.575251
            };
        },
        link: function(scope , element, attrs , ngModel){
            var mapOptions;
            var googleMap;
            var searchMarker;
            var searchLatLng;

            searchLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.searchLocation.latitude, scope.searchLocation.longitude);

            mapOptions = {
                center: searchLatLng,
                zoom: 12,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            googleMap = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);

            searchMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: searchLatLng,
                map: googleMap,
                draggable: true
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(searchMarker, 'dragend', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.searchLocation.latitude = searchMarker.getPosition().lat();
                    scope.searchLocation.longitude = searchMarker.getPosition().lng();
                });
            });

            scope.$watch('searchMarker', function(value){
                var myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.searchLocation.latitude, scope.searchLocation.longitude);
                searchMarker.setPosition(myPosition);
            }, true);
        }
    }
  });
```

1. You don't need [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). Especially ngModel.$render. It is needed for inputs, which is not your case.
2. Container for map has to have initial size: width and height.